# Using variable to call element of list is returning "List index out of range"

Tags: python, list

I'm new to coding and have been having this problem for a bit, I've tried looking around and messing with the code but can't seem to find the problem as simple as the solution probably is.

My code is:

```
import random
import sys
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

clear()

filt = int(raw_input("What number do you want your results to be filtered         by?"))

clear()

gorl = raw_input("Do you want to filter numbers greater or lower than %i?" %(filt))

clear()

ammvar = int(raw_input("How many variables do you want to filter?"))

clear()

y = ammvar

var_list_remainder = []

var_list = []

varnum = 1

while ammvar > 0:
    var_list.append(int(raw_input("Variable %i:"%(varnum))))
    varnum = varnum + 1
    ammvar = ammvar - 1

clear()

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")


if gorl == "greater":
    x = 0
    while y > 0:
        if var_list[x] > filt:
            var_list_remainder.append(var_list[x])
            x = x + 1
            y = y - 1
        elif var_list[x] <= filt:
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1
elif gorl == "lower":
    x = 0
    while y < 0:
        if var_list[x] > filt:
            var_list_remainder.append(var_list[x])
            x = x + 1
            y = y - 1
        elif var_list[x] >= filt:
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1

print(var_list_remainder)

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

If I run this and I get to input my variables then the following error occurs:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:/Users/D/OneDrive/Documents/Intro To Python/GreaterOrLower.py", line 43, in

if var_list[x] > filt:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: style tip: if you are going to *name* your anonymous function, just use a full-function definition: `clear = lambda: os.system('cls')`

Comment: Aside from that, what is this code *suppose to do*? What debugging attempts have you tried yourself?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory -- you are trying to evaluate `var_list[x]` when `x` is too large. Why do you think that `x` is always in range? Your code is repeatedly adding `1` to it and not checking if the result it too big.

Comment: "List index out of range" means that you are trying to access element N of some list, but that list has fewer than N elements.  You will probably find the error pretty quickly if you `print(len(var_list), x)` in both loops in the last section of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use `y` as an auxiliary variable to iterate through the list `var_list` (since it tells the loop when to stop) and it's not stoping the loop on time. I would change the way you iterate through `var_list` and use a simpler approach.

I only changed this bit of code:

```
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")


if gorl == "greater":
    for item in var_list:  # item will take the value of each element in the list for each iteration
        if item > filt:  # we check if the item is greater
            var_list_remainder.append(item)  # we append it
elif gorl == "lower":
    for item in var_list:  # item will take the value of each element in the list for each iteration
        if item < filt:  # we check if the item is lower
            var_list_remainder.append(item)  # we append it

print(var_list_remainder)

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

I would change a few more things but those are not related to question.

Answer (score 0):

Because y can be incremented, the while loop can run more than ammvar, thus x can grow bigger than the size of the list. When getting an item by an index bigger than the size of the list (minus one, because it is zero indexed) you get an exception.
Your algorithm is not clear enough to me for me to fix it.